# Add extra detail to MKPointAnnotation other than title and subtitle

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpointannotation

I wish to pass informations from a Pin annotation to another viewController.I can pass the title and subtitle of the annotation but I need to pass some extra information along with these.  Is there a way to add extra information to a MKPointAnnotation other than just title and subtitle?

here I have the pin title and subtitle set so it appears on the map:

```
    var zoopin = MKPointAnnotation()
    zoopin.coordinate = zoo
    zoopin.title = "The zoo"
    zoopin.subtitle = "hello this is the zoo"
    mapView.addAnnotation(zoopin)
```

the title and subtitle are then passed to my info view controller using:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "info") {
        if let annotation = sender as? MKAnnotationView {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! info
            detailViewController.titleText  = annotation.annotation?.title ?? ""
            detailViewController.detaileText = annotation.annotation?.subtitle ?? ""

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your own annotation, new file or class

```
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var EXTRA_INFORMATION: String?
    var title: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

and use it instead of normal MKPointAnnotation

```
var zoopin = MyAnnotation()
zoopin.coordinate = zoo
zoopin.title = "The zoo"
zoopin.subtitle = "hello this is the zoo"
zoopin.EXTRA_INFORMATION = "that is your new extra info that you wanted to add?"
mapView.addAnnotation(zoopin)
```

Comment: I've been playing around with it there I can't seem to get it to work because I don't understand it. could you explain it in a little more detail please?

Comment: check edit, there is really nothing to understand you are making your annotation that contain " Is there a way to add extra information" that what you want

Comment: It was popping up as 'missing argument for parameter "coordinate" in call' earlier on. What does this mean?

Comment: look at initialization, it requires coordinate, you can modify that